# How do I add a radius circle to Bing Maps?

Tags: jquery, ajax, bing-maps

I've seen it done here: 
http://www.somebody4u.com/Profile/Live

but I can't find a way to do it with the api (ajax).

Comment: 4 others that land here: bing maps v8 circle answer can be derived from here: [bing msdn forum answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bd041bbd-b4be-40b6-ae68-8b48aba83b64/how-to-create-accuracy-circle-in-bing-map-v8?forum=bingmapsajax)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bing Maps V7 does not include a draw circle method.

The circle has to be "aproximated" by drawing several small segments.

```
var key = .....; // API access key

var MM = Microsoft.Maps;
var R = 6371; // earth's mean radius in km

var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(this.element[0], {credentials: key, disableKeyboardInput: true});

var radius = ...;      //radius of the circle
var latitude = ...;    //latitude of the circle center
var longitude = ...;   //longitude of the circle center

var backgroundColor = new Microsoft.Maps.Color(10, 100, 0, 0);
var borderColor = new Microsoft.Maps.Color(150, 200, 0, 0);

var lat = (latitude * Math.PI) / 180;     
var lon = (longitude * Math.PI) / 180;
var d = parseFloat(radius) / R;
var circlePoints = new Array();

for (x = 0; x <= 360; x += 5) {
    var p2 = new MM.Location(0, 0);
    brng = x * Math.PI / 180;
    p2.latitude = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat) * Math.cos(d) + Math.cos(lat) * Math.sin(d) * Math.cos(brng));

    p2.longitude = ((lon + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(d) * Math.cos(lat), 
                     Math.cos(d) - Math.sin(lat) * Math.sin(p2.latitude))) * 180) / Math.PI;
            p2.latitude = (p2.latitude * 180) / Math.PI;
            circlePoints.push(p2);
}

var polygon = new MM.Polygon(circlePoints, { fillColor: backgroundColor, strokeColor: borderColor, strokeThickness: 1 });

map.entities.push(polygon);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better, there is now an example in the V8 documentation.  [Geolocation Accuracy Circle Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-concepts/spatial-math-module-examples/geolocation-accuracy-circle-example)

Edit: Okay, the above example looks a lot like the code from the other answer here--and, the code does not work.  I reported it on the docs page.  I got a working example on the Bing Maps Dev Center.

[Generate a regular polygon](https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/generateregularpolygon)

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {});
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath', function () {
    // Get locations of a regular hexagon, 5 miles from each vertex the map center
    var locations = Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.getRegularPolygon(map.getCenter(), 5, 6, Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.DistanceUnits.Miles);
    var polygon = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(locations, null);
    map.entities.push(polygon);
});
```

If you change the 6 to 36, you will get a circle.

Comment: I was able to find the bug in their code (looks like they just ignored you when you reported it). Line 19 must look like the following `var path = Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.getRegularPolygon(loc, position.coords.accuracy, 36, Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.DistanceUnits.Meters);` Note how I referenced the enum 'DistanceUnits'.